# ¿Como puedo optimizar este algoritmo?

Tags: c#, algoritmos, optimización

Soy nueva en programación y el profe nos dejó de tarea un algoritmo voraz que devuelva y/o desglose una cantidad de dinero en monedas, por ejemplo:
$25 = 2 monedas de $10 
      1 monedas de $5
y según yo, mi algoritmo está correcto ya que devuelve el cambio correctamente pero el profe me dice que lo optimice mas y la verdad ya intenté de todo y no me sale, espero me puedan ayudar de corazón :(
Mi algoritmo es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tienes infinitas monedas de 20, 10, 5, 2 y 1?

Comment: No, depende de lo que yo ingrese a la variable 'dinero'

Comment: ¿ Podrías colocar tu código como **texto** y no como imágenes ? Muchos usuarios no prestarán atención a tu pregunta si no pueden leer el código, y es imposible copiar/pegar una imagen para probar. ¿ Has pasado por el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) ? ¿ Y por el [centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help) ? Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

En tu código estás abusando de los bucles, realmente no se necesita bucles para realizar dicha acción, en lugar de basar tu código en la suma/resta  básalo en la división

La función **Math.Truncate** devuelve la parte entera de un número decimal.
Así que dividendo la cantidad de dinero pendiente de repartir entre el valor de cada moneda, se puede obtener cuantas monedas se deben utilizar.

**Ejemplo**

```
        if (dinero >= 20 && UsarMonedasDe20)
        {
            var CantidadDeMonedas = Math.Truncate(dinero / 20);
            m20 = m20 + CantidadDeMonedas;
            dinero = dinero - (CantidadDeMonedas * 20);
        }


        if (dinero >= 10 && UsarMonedasDe10)
        {
            var CantidadDeMonedas = Math.Truncate(dinero / 10);
            m10 = m10 + CantidadDeMonedas;
            dinero = dinero - (CantidadDeMonedas * 10);
        }


        if (dinero >= 5 && UsarMonedasDe5)
        {
            var CantidadDeMonedas = Math.Truncate(dinero / 5);
            m5 = m5 + CantidadDeMonedas;
            dinero = dinero - (CantidadDeMonedas * 5);
        }



        if (dinero >= 2 && UsarMonedasDe2)
        {
            var CantidadDeMonedas = Math.Truncate(dinero / 2);
            m2 = m2 + CantidadDeMonedas;
            dinero = dinero - (CantidadDeMonedas * 2);
        }



        if (dinero >= 1 && UsarMonedasDe1)
        {
            var CantidadDeMonedas = dinero;
            m1 = m1 + CantidadDeMonedas;
            dinero = dinero - (CantidadDeMonedas);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo usaria arrays para hacerlo mas corto, disculpa que lo envie en C espero te sirva.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void){
    int denominacion[]={20,10,5,2,1},contador[]={0,0,0,0,0},dinero;
    dinero=25;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        while (dinero>=denominacion[i])
        {
            dinero-=denominacion[i];
            contador[i]++;
        }
    }
    printf("El cambio son:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("%i monedas de %i pesos\n",contador[i],denominacion[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

si dinero=25 entonces arrojaría lo siguiente

```
El cambio son:
1 monedas de 20 pesos
0 monedas de 10 pesos
1 monedas de 5 pesos
0 monedas de 2 pesos
0 monedas de 1 pesos
```